# unzip file to same location in jenkins using fileOperations

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to unzip files from DEVBUILDS and when it finds the zip file it should unzip it to the same location with the same file name but no zip extension. Not sure what to put in targetLocation.

When I add a specific location like "\\1.1.1.1\exampleFolder\targetFolder" it does unzip but since there are many zip files in DEVBUILDS folder and subfolders in DEVBUILDS, I am not sure what to do?

```
I did targetLocation: '**/**' or targetLocation: '.' or targetLocation: '/**' but none of this worked.
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
stage('DevBuildsUnzip'){
    
def DEVBUILDS = "\\\\1.1.1.1\\exampleFolder\\sourceZipFolder"

dir(DEVBUILDS) {
    fileOperations([
        fileUnZipOperation(filePath: '**/**.zip', targetLocation: '')
    ])
}
```

}

Comment: Separate concerns. First get a list of ZIP file paths and store these into an array. Then loop over the array and call `fileUnzipOperation` for each ZIP file. Example to create path array using `sh` step: `def zipPaths = (sh script: "find '$DEVBUILDS' -type f -name '*.zip'", returnStdout: true).trim().split('\r?\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Loop over this with your list of zips:

```
def appPackageFolder = buildName.replaceAll(".zip\$", "")
          sh "unzip -q ${buildName} -d '${appPackageFolder}'"
```

this will unzip your files with the same name, the variable saves your destination or output folder name.  could be your loop variable or zip file name.